# Dynamically Create multiple combobox Codebehind & bind the value through wcf in silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, combobox

This is the code i have written to dynamically generate Controls:

```
private void GenCtrl(string type, int typeid,string sql)
            {
                string id = Convert.ToString(typeid);
            if (type == "TextBox")
                {// created for TextBox
                 }
           else if (type == "ComboBox")
                {
                  ComboBoxEdit  cb = new ComboBoxEdit();
                    cb.Name = "cb" + id; 
                 // this is to set unique id if more than 1 combobox created.

                   cb.Height = 20;
                    cb.Width = 100;
                    cb.Margin = new Thickness(2, 2, 0, 0);
                    cb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    cb.Text = "Show All";
                    stctrl.Children.Add(cb);                       
                    ComboBoxEdit cbx = (ComboBoxEdit)cb.FindName(cb.Name);
                    cb.DisplayMember = "Name";

                    if(filsql !=null)
                    ServRef.GetComboBoxlistAsync(sql); //this would retrieve the list and attach to the combobox.

                    //ctlst.Add(cb.Name, type);
                }
}
```

//**WCF Service reference**

---

```
ServRef.GetComboBoxlistCompleted += new EventHandler<GetComboBoxlistCompletedEventArgs>(ServRef_GetComboBoxlistCompleted);


        void ServRef_GetComboBoxlistCompleted(object sender, GetComboBoxlistCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            cb.ItemsSource = e.Result;
            cb.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
```

The problem i am facing while binding  two combobox is created ex : cb1,cb2( dynamically created)only the control cb2 combox which is the latest get activated at ServRef_GetComboBoxlistCompleted method. i am unable to bind the value for the first control(combobox).

if my question is not clear let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to find using FindName

```
ComboBoxEdit cbx = (ComboBoxEdit)stackctrl.FindName(cb.Name);
```